# UWP Listview to freeze columns in horizontal scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP list view with 15+ columns, i wanted to freeze first 2 columns while scrolling horizontally so that user knows which row he's scrolling. 
So, Is there any possibility to freeze first 2 columns of a listview item while scrolling horizontally.

Note : I need this without using any Thirdparty controls.

This is the sample code after trying overlapping of two listviews

```
 <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="15" MinHeight="300" MaxHeight="450">
                            <Border x:Name="GridBorder1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="LightSlateGray"  Visibility="Visible"   VerticalAlignment="Top"    Grid.ColumnSpan="15" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1" MinHeight="300" MaxHeight="450" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ListView x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource NoScrollListView}">
                                        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="280"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="S.No" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Product Id" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Product Desc" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="280"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding sno,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding skuId}" Foreground="White" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemDesc }" Foreground="White" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="33" />
                                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="33" />
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />


                                            </Style>
                                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    </ListView>

                                    <ListView x:Name="ListView2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource NoScrollListView}" >
                                        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="280"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="95"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="105"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>-->
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <!--   <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>-->
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="S.No" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Product Id" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Product Desc" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="UOM" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Product Track Code" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Batch ID" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Exp Date" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="HSN Code" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Discount(%)" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Flat Dis" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>


                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Tax(%)" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="11"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="PO Qty" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>


                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="12" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="PO Price" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <!--   <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="13" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Free Qty" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>-->
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="13" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Delivery Qty" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="No of Units" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="14" Content="MRP" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="15" Content="Delivery Price" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="16" Content="Net Cost" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="17" Content="Handled By" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>
                                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="18" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Action" Style="{StaticResource newGrnButtonStyle2}"></Button>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate >
                                                <Grid >
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="280"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="95"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="105"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <!-- <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>-->
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <!--   <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>-->
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding sno,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding skuId}" Foreground="White" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemDesc }" Foreground="White" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding uom}" Foreground="White" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding itemScanCode,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}"  TabIndex="4" Margin="2" MaxLength="20"  Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtEAN" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}" LostFocus="txtEAN_LostFocus" KeyDown="txtEAN_KeyDown" ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding bactchNum , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}"  TabIndex="5" MaxLength="20" Margin="2" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtBatch" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}" LostFocus="txtBatch_LostFocus" KeyDown="txtBatch_KeyDown" ></TextBox>

                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding expiry_date,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}"  TabIndex="6" MaxLength="20" Margin="2" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtEXPDate" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}" LostFocus="txtEXPDate_LostFocus" PlaceholderText="dd/mm/yyyy" KeyDown="TxtEXPDate_KeyDown" ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding hsnCode,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}"  TabIndex="7" MaxLength="20" Margin="2" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtHsnCode" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}" PlaceholderText="HSN Code" LostFocus="TxtHsnCode_LostFocus" KeyUp="txtAutoBox_KeyUp" ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBox TabIndex="8"  MaxLength="20" Margin="1" FontSize="14" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="8" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" PlaceholderText="(%)Discount" Name="txtperDiscount" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxstyles}" TextChanging="txtAutoDeliveryQty_TextChanging" TextChanged="TxtperDiscount_TextChanged" KeyDown="TxtperDiscount_KeyDown" GotFocus="TxtperDiscount_GotFocus" ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBox  TabIndex="9" MaxLength="20" Margin="1" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Grid.Column="9" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtFlatDicount" PlaceholderText="Flat Discount" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}" TextChanging="txtAutoDeliveryQty_TextChanging" TextChanged="TxtFlatDicount_TextChanged" GotFocus="TxtFlatDicount_GotFocus" KeyDown="TxtFlatDicount_KeyDown"   ></TextBox>

                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding taxRate,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxstyles}" Margin="2" TabIndex="10"  FontSize="13" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="White"   Name="txtAutoTax"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  LostFocus="txtAutoTax_LostFocus" TextChanging="txtAutoTax_TextChanging"  KeyUp="txtAutoBox_KeyUp" ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding orderQty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding orderPrice,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed"   MaxLength="20" Margin="2" FontSize="14" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="13" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtFreeqty" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}"  ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBox  TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxstyles}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Text="{Binding suppliedQty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,2,0,3"  FontSize="14" Foreground="Black"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="13" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" IsEnabled="{Binding qtyEditable}"  Name="txtAutoDeliveryQty"  TextChanging="txtAutoDeliveryQty_TextChanging" Loaded="txtAutoDeliveryQty_Loaded" VerticalAlignment="Center" LostFocus="txtAutoDeliveryQty_LostFocus" KeyDown="TxtAutoDeliveryQty_KeyDown" GotFocus="TxtAutoDeliveryQty_GotFocus"  TabIndex="0" >

                                                    </TextBox>


                                                    <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}"  Text="{Binding pack_size}"   MaxLength="20" Margin="2" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="14" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtnoofUnit" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}"  ></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding mrp,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}"  TabIndex="1" MaxLength="20" Margin="2" FontSize="14" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="14" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Name="txtMRP" Background="White" TextAlignment="Center" LostFocus="TxtMRP_LostFocus"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  TextBoxstyles}" KeyUp="txtAutoBox_KeyUp"  ></TextBox>

                                                    <TextBox Loaded="txtAutoDeliveryCost_Loaded"  TextAlignment="Center" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Text="{Binding supplyPrice,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxstyles}" Margin="0,2,0,3" FontSize="14" x:Name="txtAutoDeliveryCost" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="15" BorderBrush="White" IsEnabled="{Binding costpriceEditable}" BorderThickness="1" Background="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanging="txtAutoDeliveryCost_TextChanging"   LostFocus="txtAutoDeliveryCost_LostFocus" KeyUp="txtAutoBox_KeyUp" TabIndex="2"></TextBox>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding totalCost,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Foreground="White"  Grid.Column="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                    <ComboBox TabIndex="3" PlaceholderText="Handled By"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="17"  Margin="0,3,0,0"  Name="comboHandeledBy" ItemsSource="{Binding objEmployeeName}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=handledBy}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource   newGrnComboStyle}" SelectionChanged="comboHandeledBy_SelectionChanged" >
                                                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                                                                    <TextBlock Name="txtEmployeeName">
                                                                     <Run Text="{Binding handledBy}"></Run>
                                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    </ComboBox>
                                                    <StackPanel ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding itemDesc}" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0.5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="18">
                                                        <Button  Grid.Row="0" Width="auto"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="btnDelete" Tapped="btnDelete_Tapped">
                                                            <Image Source="/Images/delete.png" Width="27" Height="20"></Image>
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0.5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="19">
                                                        <Button  Grid.Row="0" Width="auto"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black" Visibility="{Binding isVisible}" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="btnAdd" Tapped="btnAdd_Tapped">
                                                            <Image Source="/Images/plus_sign.png" Width="27" Height="18"></Image>
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="33" />
                                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="33" />
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />


                                            </Style>
                                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                                    </ListView>

                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

UWP native `ListView` does not provide the option to freeze a column. In fact, the column should be defined by you in the `DataTemplate`.

If you want to use `ListView` to achieve your needs, this may require two `ListView` to display side by side.

This is a piece of code used to show ideas and does not contain real content

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="FreezeListView"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FreezeRowTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind FreezeCollection}"
              />
    <ListView x:Name="DefaultListView"
              Grid.Column="1"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultRowTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind DefaultCollection}"
              />
</Grid>
```

By extracting the frozen column data and displaying it separately, the scrolling of the `DefaultListView` will not affect the `FreezeListView`.

---

From your description, the DataGrid control is also provided in UWP, which contains the properties of the frozen column. The control comes from the `WindowsCommunityToolkit`. This tool set is maintained by Microsoft. It is a supplement to the native control and is open source.

This is the relevant content of `DataGrid`, if necessary, you can view:

- [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/styling_formatting_options#5-frozen-columns)
- [Source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid)

---

**Update**

There is a `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView`, and the scrolling of the two `ListView`s is independent of each other and does not affect each other. If you want to scroll synchronously, then one idea is to put two `ListView` in the same `ScrollViewer` control, and in order not to completely invalidate the virtualization of `ListView`, we need to modify the `ListView` control template

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoScrollListView" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowsScrollingPlaceholders" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <ItemsPresenter Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}" FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}" FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

*Usage*

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView1" Style="{StaticResource NoScrollListView}"/>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NoScrollListView}"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Good suggestion to have 2 listviews , but there got another problem during vertical scroll
as both the listviews can't be scrolled at a time.
I don't want to use toolkit datagrid as it's a heavy control, i need a light weight native control.

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer, please check it.

Comment: I used the same code, vertical scrolling is okay. but horizontal scrolling is not coming. I even tried keeping 2nd listview inside a scroll viewer. It didn't work

Comment: I can provide an idea: scroll horizontally, which means that the width of the current control exceeds the width of the `ScrollViewer`, so you can change the second column definition to `<ColumnDefinition Width=" Auto"/>`, so the list will not be limited by the width of the parent container. But this just allows the list to scroll horizontally, and does not fix a ListView. If you want to do this, you need to overlap, that is, add an additional property `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` to the second ListView. Parallel and Overlap are two different states, you need to switch according to the situation.

Comment: Tried overlapping case, it didn't get succeeded. I have attached sample code to my question. Can you please look into it.

Comment: First of all, ListView1 as a fixed column, it should be below ListView2 in XAML. Secondly you need to set `HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` for ScrollViewer. However, according to the current layout, you cannot achieve your needs. Because when vertical scrolling, we want to make two ListViews in the same ScrollViewer, but when fixing ListView1, we only need to let ListView2 scroll, and the state transition is more complicated. DataGrid has encapsulated these, if you are curious about how DataGrid does this, you can check the source code (already in answer).

Comment: So, for listview it's not possible for frozen columns. Thanks for the suggestions. will use datagrid.